# Regex for extracting all words between word and character

Tags: regex, r

i know basic of regex performing with R. But here i have a file like :

> **[2016-04-28 14:00:06,603],,,,,SERVICE_ID=441,DEBUG,DBSEntryServlet,DBSEntryServlet: delegateToRequestManager:: SERVICE_ID=541,SERVICE_ID=9981
>
> [2016-04-28 14:00:06,608],,,,,,DEBUG,DBSEntryServlet,10.91.39.143:60801 SERVICE_ID=00234,SERVICE_ID=11134,IMD=6767**

I wanted to extract timestamp alongwith all the SERVICE_ID in that line.

So, my expected output is:

> [2016-04-28 14:00:06,603]  SERVICE_ID=441     SERVICE_ID=541     SERVICE_ID=9981
>
> [2016-04-28 14:00:06,608]  SERVICE_ID=00234   SERVICE_ID=11134

The code which I tried was only extracting one SERVICE_ID.

```
library(qdapRegex)

a <- readLines("C:\\MY_FOLDER\\vinita\\sample.txt")

testi <- rm_between(a,"SERVICE_ID",",",extract = T)
```

Comment: Is the leading `**` supposed to be there in the first line ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We replace the 2 or more `,` with `" "` to get 'str2', then using regex lookarounds, we match one or more space (`\\s+`) that follows the `]`) followed by characters (`.*`) till the end of the string, replace it with `""` so that we can extract the `[2016-04..,03]` part. From the 'str2', we extract the substrings "SERVICE_ID=" followed by numbers (`\\d+`) into a `list`, `paste` them together and finally `paste` it with the 'str3'.

```
library(stringr)
str2 <- gsub(",{2,}", " ", str1)
str3 <- sub("(?<=\\])\\s+.*", "", str2, perl = TRUE)
paste(str3, sapply(str_extract_all(str2, "SERVICE_ID=\\d+"), paste, collapse=" "))
#[1] "[2016-04-28 14:00:06,603] SERVICE_ID=441 SERVICE_ID=541 SERVICE_ID=9981"
#[2] "[2016-04-28 14:00:06,608] SERVICE_ID=00234 SERVICE_ID=11134"
```

#### data

```
 str1 <- c("[2016-04-28 14:00:06,603],,,,,SERVICE_ID=441,DEBUG,DBSEntryServlet,DBSEntryServlet: delegateToRequestManager:: SERVICE_ID=541,SERVICE_ID=9981",
"[2016-04-28 14:00:06,608],,,,,,DEBUG,DBSEntryServlet,10.91.39.143:60801 SERVICE_ID=00234,SERVICE_ID=11134,IMD=6767")
```

Comment: Thanks Akrun, absolutly correct correct :). But since i didnt get your "str3" statement. Could you please explain the regex of that? I modified a bit so, and posting it.

Comment: @ShaliniBaranwal `(?<=)` is a lookbehind..it is assuring that a `]` is followed by one or more space..

Comment: @ShaliniBaranwal  I added some description.

Answer (score 0):

```
str1 <- c("[2016-04-28 14:00:06,603],,,,,SERVICE_ID=441,DEBUG,DBSEntryServlet,DBSEntryServlet: delegateToRequestManager:: SERVICE_ID=541,SERVICE_ID=9981",
      "[2016-04-28 14:00:06,608],,,,,,DEBUG,DBSEntryServlet,10.91.39.143:60801   SERVICE_ID=00234,SERVICE_ID=11134,IMD=6767")
 str2 <- gsub(",{2,}", " ", str1)
 str4 <- sub("\\].*","",str2,perl = TRUE)
 str5 <- sub("\\[","",str4,perl = T)

 service_ids <- sapply(str_extract_all(str2,"SERVICE_ID=\\d+"), function(x){paste(x,collapse = " ")})
 net <- cbind(str5,service_ids)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: No need of Extra steps str4 and str5.
Simply use the `gsub("\\[|\\].*", "", str2)`